# How to fix Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android

How to fix following Exception in fragment when launching TakePicture in Landscape mode?

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher with contract androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$StartActivityForResult@3363683 and input Intent { cmp=com.foodieandroid/.activity.SaveTextActivity (has extras) }. You must ensure the ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch().

Thanks,
Gaurav Kapoor

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix

Adding the following change for Parent Activity Class in manifest file fixed the problem.

**android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"**

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainTabActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```